# HTML: slideshow is not recognised as an element in the main content of the page

Tags: html, css, slideshow

## Situation:

I am making an own site, today I was facing a little problem..

On my page I'm using a **wrap**, in the wrap I'm using three columns, in the middle, the **main**, I'm using a grey image as a background. In the main I want some text and a slideshow, but the image has to **adapt**, when I'm using simple text this works(the image is as long as the text).

## Problem:

Under my text I want a simple slideshow, nothing really special. But when I place the slideshow in the main, the image does **not** adapt..? It is not recognised as an element in the main?

## Code:

For the **html** page this is my code:

```
    <div id="main">
       <p id="Title">Welcome</p>    
       <p>Some text here</p>
       <p>
           <div id="slideshow2">

               <div class="slide active"><img src="images/1.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" /></a>
               </div>
               <div class="slide"><img src="images/2.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" /></a>
               </div>
               <div class="slide"><img src="images/3.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" /></a>
               </div>

           </div>
        </p>

    </div>
```

I'm using a script to operate the slideshow, this is working perfect, so no need to post this.

In the **CSS** I'm doing this:

```
    #slideshow2{
      position: absolute;
    }
    #slideshow2 .slide {
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      z-index:8;
      opacity:0.0;
    }
    #slideshow2 div.active {
      z-index:10;
      opacity:1.0;
    }
    #slideshow2 div.last-active {
      z-index:9;
    }

    #main{
      padding-top: 1px;
      padding-bottom: 3px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 800px;
      background: url("images/main.png") repeat;
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

And the **wrap**:

```
    #wrap{
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 1240px;
      height: auto;
      min-height: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
```

I hope someone can help me because I do not know how I can fix this..

## Update:

I tried to do this:

```
    <p id="slideshow2">
        <div class="slide active"><img src="images/1.png" alt="Slideshow Image 1" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="images/2.png" alt="Slideshow Image 2" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide"><img src="images/3.png" alt="Slideshow Image 3" /></a>
        </div>
   </p>
```

Here the main recognises the slideshow as an element but all the images are placed under eachother and not above eachother..

**Script:**

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function slideSwitch() {
        var $active = $('#slideshow div.active');

        if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow div:last');

        var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow div:first');

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
        }

        $(function() {
        setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3500 );
        });
    </script>
```

Please help :)

**Thank you**

Comment: did you give any size to your elements ?

Comment: No I didn't but I don't think the problem lies with the size..? The images are all the same size I tried using a table with a specific size but the main does not recognise this either..

Comment: I tried giving it a size, heigth:439px; and width:208px; but the problem is still there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the slideshow script you are using require you to have the anchor close tags without a corresponding opening tag for some reason ? If not, perhaps it is gakking on it.

Also, what do you mean by "adapt" in this question ?

but ok, the problem is that absolutely positioned elements leave the normal document flow. Their height doesn't contribute to the height of their container. So yes, you are correct, they are not recognized as an element within main for the purposes of element height. As it is now, #main will have a height based only on the text outside of #slideshow2.

As a quick fix, try this:

```
#slideshow2 {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}
```

or whatever the height of your images is, if they are consistent

If the size of your slides are variable, add this to slideSwitch() :

```
var slideHeight = $next.height();
$next.parent().height( slideHeight );
```

like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow div.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow div:last');

    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow div:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
    $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
    }

    // set the #slideshow2 height
    $next.parent().height( $next.height() );

    $(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 3500 );
    });
</script>
```

Although maybe this is all nonsense, and the problem is that you've changed the ID of #slideshow to #slideshow2, but your script still references #slideshow

Comment: I eddited my question and added the script, the background(the grey one) has no actually height, it has to fit to the text in it, do you understand? With normal text it works and adapts to the text inside, but the slideshow is not recognises as an element(the background does not adapt only to the text inside, so the slideshow is actually out of the main)

Comment: Yes I changed the id, I wanted two different slideshows on one page but if I use the same id and move one then the other one moves as well. So I need two scripts then?

Comment: I implemented your code, I used two scripts and it worked :) thank you :)
Is it possible to use one script instead? And can I put the slideshow in the center? Because using "align="center"" does not work..?

Comment: Yes, you can use one script by passing an argument to the existing script and changing it to operate on that argument like ... function slideSwitch( aSlideShow ) {} . It's kind of awkward to follow the code and markup right now, so try to stuff it into a jsfiddle, and I'll take a look

Comment: I tried but I do not know if it is going to help, anyway here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/erEse/

Comment: Btw: I tried using two scripts but that does not seem to work.. None of the slideshows actually changes.. They keep showing one image, I trued to figure it out but I do not know, the script does not seem to work with that one line of code you added..? I deleted that line and the script worked again.. Please help :) Thank you

Comment: UPDATE: I used a table to give the slideshow a position, so now the only question is how do I let both script work together? Because I used two script for two slideshows but if I run my page only one actually works.. Do you want me to post a nex question? Or is it ok to answer here..?

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideshow2{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Should have a size, since content is absolute too.

Comment: I tried giving it a size, heigth:439px; and width:208px; 
but the problem is still there..

Comment: i'm back :), could you do a jsfiddle.net or a codepen, so it is easier for everyone to fork your code and let you see solutions we propose :)

Comment: Forgive me but I'm not that good in making jsfiddle files... I tried three times but is did not work.. I'm so sorry.. Please do not downvote me for that, noboddy is perfect.. I'm sorry, I'll keep trying but I can not guarantee a result.

Comment: it's okay, and you got your answer. these jsfiddle or similar tools are  usefull for quick test. take time somes to play with them.